# How to hide a certain column of a table using antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Sample code below

```
{
title: 'Site', 
dataIndex: 'site'
}
```

I want to hide the site column and im still new to the antd react ui.
And theres no show/hide function in column API of antd docs.
I want to hide it after a certain condition has been met like there are 2 user types. Admin user and General user.

```
if(user_role = admin_user){
show column
elseif(user_role = general_user){
hide column
}
```

Comment: need more details, like when u want to hide the column. whether when the table loads or after some event is fired.

Comment: Hiii, i updated the description :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   getColumns = (userRole) => {
        switch(userRole){
          case 'AdminUser': { return  //return admin user columns here }
          case 'GeneralUser': { return //return the genral user columns here }
          default: { return //handle other cases.. or raise error}

      }
}
```

In your table component call the function.(Assuming your state has the user role)

```
<Table columns = {this.getColumns(this.state.userRole)} />
```